# Calling Remove in List<T>.ForEach only deletes alternating items?

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, lambda

I have a list of objects and I want to remove all the ones that satisfy a condition. Here is my code:

```
var listCurrentBuzzCompaigns = _buzzService.GetAllActiveCompaigns().ToList();

listCurrentBuzzCompaigns.ForEach(x => {
    if (x.MayaMembership.MayaProfile.MayaProfileId == profile_id)
        listCurrentBuzzCompaigns.Remove(x);
});
```

But one campaign is removed, the next one isn't, the next one is, the next one isn't. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're modifying the list while iterating over it, which is no good. Use the [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method instead:

```
listCurrentBuzzCompaigns.RemoveAll(x => x.MayaMembership.MayaProfile.MayaProfileId == profile_id);
```

Normally, when you use the `foreach` keyword to iterate through a `List<T>`, the enumerator will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if it detects that the list has been modified. This behavior is designed to prevent exactly the sort of bug you encountered. Unfortunately, the `List<T>.ForEach` method doesn't use an enumerator internally, and so no exception is thrown to warn you about a possible bug. This inconsistency between `foreach` and `ForEach` seems like a design flaw to me.

**UPDATE:** As AlanT notes, an alternate technique would be to filter out the items you don't want *before* calling `ToList`. Here's how to do it:

```
var listCurrentBuzzCompaigns = _buzzService.GetAllActiveCompaigns()
    .Where(x.MayaMembership.MayaProfile.MayaProfileId != profile_id)
    .ToList();
```

Notice that I've inverted the condition by changing `==` to `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

In the snippet shown you might be better use a where() clause to filter the campaigns when getting them rather than trying to remove them after they have been retrieved.

e.g.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {

   var campaigns = new List<Campaign>(){
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Jan"},
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Jan"},
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Feb"},
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Mar"},
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Jan"},
       new Campaign {ProfileId = "Jan"},
   };


   var notJanCampaigns = campaigns.Where(c => c.ProfileId != "Jan");

   Assert.AreEqual(2, notJanCampaigns.Count());

}

class Campaign {
    public string ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

In your code you would filter on

```
x.MayaMembership.MayaProfile.MayaProfileId != profile_id
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove elements from a collection while iterating over it, iterate over it backwards like this:

```
List<Smurf> smurfs = GetSomeSmurfs();
for (in i = smurfs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   Smurf smurfToRemove = smurfs[i];
   if(conditionToRemoveSmurf)
   {
      //Do whatever you need with that smurf before removing it. 
      //(Dispose(), give to azrael, whatever)
      smurfs.Remove(smurfToRemove);
   }
}
```

The corresponding extension method to achieve this is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Why would you make an extension method to do this when List already has an actual method that does this (`RemoveAll`)?

Comment: This is meant to be more flexible than RemoveAll (i.e: you can execute code before/after each remove). But indeed, you could just as well build around RemoveAll.

Comment: If it's going to be that specific then it wouldn't make sense as an extension method.

Comment: It does make sense if you work on an app that does that repeatedly. Just add 2 parameters of type Action(). one runs before the remove, the other one after. You thus hide the for loop logic that is not so readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove stuff from a sequence you're iterating over!

So, instead do:

```
var x = listCurrentBuzzCompaigns.Where(x => x.MayaMemberShip.MayaProfile.PayaProfileId == profile_id).Single();
listCurrentBuzzCompaigns.Remove(x);
```

Comment: @ucef, but you should use Michael Liu's solution instead!